# How to connect rs232 board to PI

Tags: gpio, serial

How to connect [this](http://www.mikroe.com/add-on-boards/communication/max3232/) rs232 board to the PI?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To connect this board to the Raspberry Pi you'll need 4 wires:

```
GND to ground pin
VCC to +3.3V pin
TX/RX to the serial RX/TX pins correspondingly
CTS/RTS can be happily ignored
```

Make sure your power supply has enough juice to spare, MAX3232 uses voltage multiplication to achieve RS232C 13V levels, that might require some power.

Comment: I need this 4 wires right http://www.mikroe.com/img/development-tools/compontents/wire-jumpers/wire_jumpers_male_to_male.jpg ? I will use just PI and this 3232 board so I guess it would be ok power vise. Will usb to serial converter cables work on PI?

Comment: actually, USB to serial is the preferred way to go. however, depending on the other side, you might not need a full blown RS232-C, but just TTL-serial, that's cheaper, easier to use with microcontrollers and less power hungry.

Comment: RS232 was designed to send data up to 1000' (~300m) hence the bipolar ±15 voltage swing. Very few modern devices require (or support) this and many only swing TTL levels. Protection is usually desirable, so an adaptor is recommended, rather than direct connection to the Pi's 3.3v serial.